# How can I avoid the horizontal scrollbar in a ReST table?

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I have this table in ReST markup:

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Option Line Kind          | Distinguishing Characteristic                                   |
+===========================+=================================================================+
| **Reference**             | The option name is called a (node) reference, if the value\     |
|                           | of an option is a predefined keyword for the current node\      |
|                           | class. Because the option's value is a keyword, it can not\     |
|                           | be an interpolated value.                                       |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| **Option**                | The option uses a defined option name valid for the current\    |
|                           | node class. The value can be a fixed or interpolated string.    |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| **User Defined Variable** | Otherwise an option line is a user defined variable. It can\    |
|                           | have fixed or interpolated string values.                       |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sphinx (ReadTheDocs theme) generates a horizontal scrollbar instead of breaking the content in column 2. The result is this mess:

[image]

What do I need to change in ReST (or the RTFD theme??) to let it break the text?

---

**Edit:**

The answer from @aflp91 results in this table:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a _static/custom.css file with

```
.wy-table-responsive table td {
white-space: normal;
}
```

Don't forget to declare it into conf.py:

```py
    def setup(app):
        app.add_stylesheet('custom.css')
```

Works in my test…

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property for table:

```
Overflow-x : hidden;
overflow-y : hidden;
```

Comment: I'm not used to CSS... So this forces line breaks? I don't want just hidden scrollbars.

Comment: The question is also: How should I edit the generated table?