# New line in cell sphinx csv-table

Tags: csv, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

With this symbol "|" had broke my table. And after new lines have blank line. 
How i can have multiple normal lines in csv-table cell sphinx alabast

```
.. csv-table:: 
:header: Version, Date, Description
:widths: 15, 20, 50


34343, 02/04/2015, "| Added *httsdfsdps* support"
3434, 14/11/2014, "| Added *folsdfsdlow* parameter to *hgfhfg*"
34343, 13/05/2014, "| Added *fdsf* parameter to *dfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgdfgdf*"
21321, 29/10/2013, "| Added *sdfsdf* parameter to *dfgsgfds*           
| Deprecated afsfsdf interface"
312321, 05/03/2013, "| Added *dsfsdfsddsfsd* parameter to *dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdf*             
| Documented *dfgdgd*"
213211, 28/02/2013, "Added *!=* operator in *fghfghfg*"
2132132, 26/02/2013, "Added *dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd* in *fghf*"
213219, 07/02/2013, "| Added *jsonhash* event format
| Added *filter* parameter in event connection
| Added *group* and *map* parameter to *nph-muu-sf*"
21321321, 30/01/2013, "| Added *height* parameter in *dfgdfgdfdfg*
| Added *dfgdfgdfgdf* in dfgdfgdfgdf"
```

[image: csv table]

Comment: Is there any help in this this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641252/how-can-i-avoid-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-rest-table)?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "broke my table". Are you referring to the missing border between the 21321 and 312321 rows? Have you tried any other Sphinx theme besides "alabaster"? What version of Sphinx do you use?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, missing border and blank lines at end of cells is my problem. Sphinx version is 1.3.1 but tried and on 1.4.8 and the same problems.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the missing border. It works for me with alabaster theme (tested with Sphinx 1.3.5 and 1.5.1).

Comment: Thank you guys! Did like @Humbalan said. Work's perfect.
Added this code in _static/style.css
`table .line-block {
margin-bottom: 0;
}`

Comment: Guys have the last question :) What I need to do with this question. Delete? Or how i can close with @Humbalan comment like answer?

Comment: @Андрей: copied my advice to the "answer" field and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mzjn already has mentioned: it depends on the theme you use whether a table has borders at the end of cells. You can check this with the developer tools of the e .g. firefox browser. If in the "table.docutils td" definition (css) there is a line like "border-width: 1px 0px;" it is the theme's responsibility. In this case you could override this definition in an own "layout.html". More information in [Sphinx Templating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/templating.html)

Comment: IMHO it is not very clear what the actual steps are. You don't need to edit layout.html. What is needed is a custom CSS file with `margin-bottom` set to a suitable value for the line-block (similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/34227635/407651).

Comment: @mzjn: you are right, my description is not very precise. The mentioned thread shows a possible solution. But you could have a <style> section in layout.html as well. My current solution is a css file and in layout.html the link {% set css_files = css_files + ["_static/layout.css"] %}.

Comment: if you put a file `custom.css` in the `_static` repertory of your reST sources, it will be copied over automatically to the html build, and it will be linked to automatically from html source.